# Passing 2D array as pointer, gcc warning incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

I have the following versions of passing 2D array as pointer.

**Version 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>  

void disp(int a[][5])
{
    printf("a[0][3] = %d\n", a[0][3]); /* a[0][3] = 4 */
}

int main ()
{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    disp(a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void(*callDisplay)(int*);

void disp(int a[][5])
{
    printf("a[0][3] = %d\n", a[0][3]); /* a[0][3] = 4 */
}

int main ()
{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    callDisplay fn = (callDisplay) &disp;
    fn(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Version 1 rises warning `incompatible pointer type. expected int (*)[5] but argument is of type int *` as expected. However, (Version 2) calling the same function with pointer is compiling without any such warnings.

gcc options: `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0`

Could somebody pass light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the cast when assigning the function pointer you get:

```
tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp.c:13:22: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     callDisplay fn = &disp;
```

The cast is suppressing this warning even though by casting to a function pointer of a different type you have invoked undefined behavior when you call the function pointer.  Basically, you should never need to cast a function pointer as it will hide any warnings like this.

If you fix the function pointer you get the following code:

```
typedef void(*callDisplay)(int[][5]);

void disp(int a[][5])
{
    printf("a[0][3] = %d\n", a[0][3]); /* a[0][3] = 4 */
}

int main ()
{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    callDisplay fn = &disp;
    fn(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Which when you compile you get the same warning as your first example:

```
tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp.c:14:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fn’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     fn(a);
     ^
tmp.c:14:5: note: expected ‘int (*)[5]’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
```

Answer (score 2):

This function declaration

```
typedef void(*callDisplay)(int*);
```

has compatible argument when is called like

```
fn(a);
```

The problem is related to this casting

```
callDisplay fn = (callDisplay) &disp;
```

it is wrong.

That is the program has undefined behaviour.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to
>   a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to
>   call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.**